# Android SearchView: What is the difference between setOnFocusChangeListener() and setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener?

Tags: android, listener, searchview, onfocus, android-search

From the reference docs,

[SearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)) - Sets a listener to inform when the focus of the query text field changes.

and

[View.setOnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)) - Register a callback to be invoked when focus of this view changed.

So, in the case of a `SearchView` what is the difference between the two? Why did they need to provide `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener` when the `SearchView` already inherits `setOnFocusChangedListener` from `View` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look inside the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/SearchView.java) for `SearchView` then you'll notice that technically there's no difference in the working behavior of these two alternates. A part of code that proxies listeners is:

```
 // Inform any listener of focus changes
 mQueryTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
     public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
         if (mOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener != null) {
             mOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange(SearchView.this, hasFocus);
         }
     }
 });
```

The reason is that `SearchView` is a `ViewGroup` which serves the purpose of querying text, and by making it more imminent, a separate method with very specific name is provided, which simply proxies to the existing `setOnFocusChangeListener` method of `AutoCompleteTextView` inside.